# Are there any books in the classic Hardy Boys series where the boys don't get kidnapped?

Tags: hardy-boys, franklin-w-dixon

As far as I can see, in every single book of the original Hardy Boys series the brothers get kidnapped in chapter 19. From a cursory glance, I can tell that this applies to *The Hooded Hawk Mystery, The Mystery of the Chinese Junk, The Yellow Feather Mystery, The Firebird Rocket, The House on the Cliff,* and *The Secret of Skull Mountain*.

For this question, the "classic" series means the fifty-eight hardcover books published from 1972 to 1979, and their companion novel *The Hardy Boys Detective Handbook*. A book only counts as them not being kidnapped if *neither* of the brothers was kidnapped.

**Are there any books in the classic series that they do not get kidnapped in chapter 19?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes, there are books where they do not get kidnapped in chapter 19.**

I have a bunch of them, but not all. If anyone adds another answer with ones I missed, that would be awesome.

- ***The Secret Panel*** (25)

  In this book, they are kidnapped, but not in chapter 19. They are *rescued* in chapter 19.
- ***The Wailing Siren Mystery*** (30)

  In this book, they nearly get eaten by a wolf in chapter 19, but they are not kidnapped.
- ***The Mysterious Caravan*** (54)

  Just a little rockslide. Nothing to worry about.
- ***The Shattered Helmet*** (52)

  A daring rescue of Chet <s>the mouse</s>!
- ***The Sign of the Crooked Arrow*** (28)

  The helicopter descends...
- ***The Short-Wave Mystery*** (24)

  They lose the canoe, but they aren't kidnapped...

---

Here's a list of the books that I have, in no particular order, so that you people know what I looked through.

- *The Shattered Helmet*
- *The Mystery of the Spiral Bridge*
- *The Mystery of the Aztec Warrior*
- *The Sign of the Crooked Arrow*
- *The Mysterious Caravan*
- *The Wailing Siren Mystery*
- *The Secret Panel*
- *The Twisted Claw*
- *Mystery of the Flying Express*
- *The Clue in the Embers*
- *The Missing Chums*
- *The Masked Monkey*
- *The Witchmaster's Keys*
- *The Mystery of the Chinese Junk*
- *The Hooded Hawk Mystery*
- *The Firebird Rocket*
- *The House on the Cliff*
- *The Secret of Skull Mountain*
- *The Short-Wave Mystery*
- *While the Clock Ticked*